# Convergence of $\sum \frac{a_n}{b_n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have an infinite series $\sum \frac{a_n}{b_n}$ where terms are real numbers.

If $\sum a_n$ converges and sequence ($b_n$) converges and its limit is non-zero.

Then can I say that the series $\sum \frac{a_n}{b_n}$ converges?

Comment: Hint. Note that  if $(_n)$ converges to a non zero limit (and  $b_n\not=0$  for any $n$)  then $(1/b_n)_n$ is bounded

Answer (score 3):

No, as it turns out. One counterexample is to take $a_n = (-1)^n n^{-1/3}$ and $b_n = \big( 1 + (-1)^n n^{-1/3} \big)^{-1}$.